# Is there a quick way to have a welcome screen with select language option in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter

Can you prefer a quick way to introduce a welcome screen, in which users can select their preferred language, in my flutter app for iOS and Android?

Comment: Are you trying to ask permission for location services?

Comment: I think he asked a way to develop a welcome screen with language selection option quickly for his app

Comment: yes I building an app then I have already created a page to ask to enable notifications to the user, now I have another page where I ask to enable localization service so they can use maps service on the app

Comment: You can refer this repo : https://github.com/UttamPanchasara/flutter-in-app-localisation

Comment: I think the question was misunderstood....
I need into the welcome screens, in a specific screen ask to the user to enable localizzation service for the app on his mobile phone both for iOS and Android